# How to format a redirect URL that references a list item?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, url-rewriting

In a previous post I was looking for the formatting required to take a user back to a custom view of a list (instead of the default view for that list).

Jinxed was nice enough to provide me with a template:

"http://web.com/lists/listname/editform.aspx?Source=http://web.com/list/listname/viewname.aspx"

I have finally figured out where to add this reformatted url using sharepoint designer but the problem I have now is that the link refers to a specific item in order to populate the display or edit form with the proper information.  Currently the Url looks like this:

"http://web.com/Lists/listname/EditFormCx.aspx?ID={$thisNode/@ID}"

How do I modify this url to reference the {$thisnode/@ID} component but ALSO include the "?Source=web.com/list/lisname/viewname.aspx" Jinxed referenced?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this,

```
http://web.com/Lists/listname/EditFormCx.aspx?ID={$thisNode/@ID}&Source=web.com/list/lisname/viewname.aspx
```

Comment: I tried formatting the URL as you stated but SharePoint designer throws an error stating that a semicolon character was expected...and the form doesn't load after I publish the change.

Comment: Try using `&amp;` in place of `&`